# Colored circles from data

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, circles

I have a data file which gives x-position (`xpos`), radius, and color. I wish to draw a circle at ever `(xpos,0)` with appropriate radius and color. How do I achieve that?

I have used two approaches. The first is based on `\addplot table`, where I can get the required coloring by using `meta`. The problem in this approach is the correct circle size.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.out}
xpos    radius  color
0       1        2
1       3        4
2       5        6
3       7        8
4       11      12
5       13      14
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    ]

    \pgfplotstableread{data.out}\datatable

    \addplot+[scatter,only marks,mark=*,point meta=explicit] table [x index={0},y expr=0,meta
    index={2}] \datatable;    

\end{axis}  

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

In an alternative approach, I have experimented with loops and pgfplotstable, which gets the circle size correct. The problem in this approach is the correct coloring of the circles. I also don't know how to correctly place and scale the axis. And if I put the `\draw` commands inside the axis environment, nothing gets drawn.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.out}
%xpos    radius  color
0       1        2
1       3        4
2       5        6
3       7        8
4       11      12
5       13      14
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\myxpos}{}
  \newcommand{\myrad}{}
  \newcommand{\mycolor}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \pgfplotstableread{data.out}\datatable

    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}  
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-1}  
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\pgfmathresult} {
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{0}\of\datatable 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myxpos}{\pgfplotsretval}

      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{1}\of\datatable 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrad}{\pgfplotsretval}

      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{2}\of\datatable 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\pgfplotsretval}
      \draw[thick] (\myxpos,0) circle [radius=\myrad];
    }

  \begin{axis}[
    anchor=origin,
    colorbar,
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=-20,
    ymin=-15,
    ymax=15,
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think a problem here is that `\draw circle` is only available as a `tikz` command, with no counterpart in `pgfplots`. This forbids many of the simple color operations available in `pgfplots`.

Here is the desired output, created with `matlab` and `matlab2tikz. 
[image: Desired result, created with matlab and matlab2tikz]

Answer (score 4):

This is why you need to use `visualization depends on` key and its variants (the manual is pretty clear on this point) with the right marker type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-1,ymax=1,
  colorbar,
  visualization depends on=\thisrow{radius}\as\myrad,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\myrad cm},
  clip marker paths=true
]
\pgfplotsextra{\show\pgfplotsunitxlength}
\addplot+[scatter,only marks,mark=o,point meta=explicit,ultra thick]
    table [x index={0},y expr=0,meta index={2}]
{
xpos    radius  color
0       1        2
1       3        4
2       5        6
3       7        8
4       11      12
5       13      14
};    
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, percusse. Your solution works, but the radii are not quantitatively correct. Their relative size is ok, but their absolute size is not. This is especially apparent, if one tries to set `ymin` and `ymax`.

Comment: @Jost They are taken as dimensions without a unit the default is  `cm`. If you want to be consistent you need to scale them with the unit vectors of the axes but then you need `axis equal` etc. to avoid ellipses.

Comment: Could you point out, how the scaling is done?

Comment: @Jost What is the resulting dimension of the circle? In accordance with x or y axis? What does the number in the table represent?

Comment: The radius is given in the same dimensions as the x position. This means the first circle goes through the origin of the second circle at `(1,0)`.

Comment: @Jost See the edit, is that what you meant? ... I now see the values are slightly off though. But still most of your circles would be invisible due to clipping of the axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25753/discussion-between-jost-and-percusse).